# Android persist global preferences?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I already have a working android app with several persisted objects/classes.
But what if I add some preferences to my app? Do I also persist them an a kind of properties class to the DB?
Or are there better ways?

Comment: [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+preferences) "android preferences"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SharedPreferences`, perhaps in conjunction with a `PreferenceActivity` to supply your user with a "Settings" screen that employs the Android-standard UI for such things.